# VBA - fill range with function of cells from another range

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I am looking for a fast way to fill a range of cells with the results of a custom function, which takes as argument values from another range (equal in size). For example, I want to fill all column E with the results of `my_function` based on column A.

This is working as desired, but is slow already at 2000 cells:

```
With ActiveSheet:
    For i = 2 to 2000:
        .cells(i,5)=my_function(.cells,i,1)
    Next i
End With
```

I am looking for something like this (which fills column E with the text "Testing":

```
Set range_to_fill = ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E2000")
range_to_fill.Value="Testing"
```

but I could not find a way to write this for anything else than filling the range with a text.
First step was to just try to copy the values from column A, but this just blanks all the cells in column E (and to be honest I don't quite understand why):

```
range_to_fill.Value = Array((Range("A2:A2000").Value))
```

Comment: What does `my_function` do exactly? Maybe you should refactor it to return an array given a multi-cell input.

Comment: it is a search function; a twisted LOOKUP, basically; takes a cell's value as argument `my_function(A2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `MyFunction` needs to return a 2 dimensional array of values. Then you can use it like

```
Range("B2:B11").Value = MyFunction(Range("A2:A11").Value)
```

For example:

If you have this input:
[image]

The following function will calculate x² and output in column B

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Range("B2:B11").Value = MyFunction(Range("A2:A11").Value)
End Sub

Public Function MyFunction(ByVal InputArr As Variant) As Variant
    'create an output array at the same size as the input array
    ReDim OutputArr(LBound(InputArr, 1) To UBound(InputArr, 1), LBound(InputArr, 2) To UBound(InputArr, 2))
    
    'loop through all rows/columns of the array and calculate something
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(InputArr, 1) To UBound(InputArr, 1)
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = LBound(InputArr, 2) To UBound(InputArr, 2)
            'calculate something, here x² as an example
            OutputArr(iRow, iCol) = InputArr(iRow, iCol) * InputArr(iRow, iCol)
        Next iCol
    Next iRow
    
    MyFunction = OutputArr 'return full array in your function
End Function
```

[image]

This method will be very fast because it doesn't write every single cell but the whole range at once. Calculation is done within the array which is much faster than using cells directly.